# How to compare multiple photos quickly

Tags: photos, comparison, image-viewer

Usually, I take always 2-4 photos in a row instead of one - then  try to pick the best one. But once the differences are very small, it's hard to tell which photo is better by simple looping using Irfan View.

Is there a better tool or a trick, to zoom multiple photos simultaneously and compare them by detail?

### Detailed *dream tool* description:

I need to display variable amount of photos, ideally in some sort of split screen. I need to zoom them all together (they are always of the same resolution and contain very very similar images). I need to be able to move all the zoomed frames by same offset as well as move the zoomed image in single frame.
I need to be able to finally click on the selected photo and have the application delete/archive the others.

### What does it mean to compare photos in this case:

As I have stated above, the photos I compare are taken sequentially. This means they contain almost the same images (+-some offset if my hands shake).
What I compare are details like blinking eyes, brightness, things in background and mostly the sharpness of the photo, which may not be obvious until the photo is zoomed.

Comment: Any program that lets you display 4 pictures at once should do the trick. As such, *any* program should work. Can you please provide more detail as to what you want? I also ask how are you comparing images (although it is accessory, it might help others answer this).

Comment: I need them zoomed in, so that I can focus on details. Since they are all same resolution, it would be enough if the program just picked the same zoom and X-Y offset on all photos. But there may be more or less than 4 photos.

Comment: I compare photos by all general photo quality criteria: sharpness, eyes (did someone blink?), enviroment (is there something awkard in the background?), brightness (too bright? too dark?). Keep in mind that the photos I compare are 0.8 seconds away from each other. So they tend to be very alike, but not the same.

Comment: You should add this information to your post by editing it, as that will bump your question to the front page.

Comment: Roger that sir.

Comment: A shameless link to [https://github.com/PatWie/saccade](https://github.com/PatWie/saccade) as a linux native open-source version, because I was looking for such a tool, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm using FastStone Image Viewer for this, but I have tried XnView as well.

You can have up to four images and each fill almost a quarter of the screen. When you zoom in or out, all four images are zoomed by the same amount. When you zoom in so that the image is larger than its display area, you can click and drag on an image to pan it. As you pan, each photo is panned in unison, making it easy to compare the actual pixels in each image.

[image]

Comment: I'll make sure to download this. It's exactly what I need. Can you also pan individually?

Comment: Yes, You can zoom and/or pan each image individually. You can also overlay right to left image by pressing the green arrow (you can overlay very quickly - fast change of two images might help you to spot potential distortions in exposure, deviations in focal view, etc)